# Unable to start web server; Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

When I try to deploy the war am getting the following error. But this same war is working perfectly in another server.

2020-05-27 10:42:03.125  WARN 1254 --- [io-8080-exec-23] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d691612]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizationServerConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field

Comment: In which server you are deploying the WAR? Have you excluded the tomcat server and created a class that extends SpringBootServletInitializer?

Comment: Can you post what beans did you create? I suppose you forgot to add \@Component, \@Repository, \@Controller annotations to some beans and spring cannot create dependants

Comment: Stack trace is not finished. Do you have actuator in classpath?